# запрет добавления сегмента URI

Tags: php, codeigniter

Добрый день!
Cайт на Codeigniter!
Как мне сделать, так чтобы при добавлении uri сегмента выдавалась страница 404?
Например, есть url вида: http://site.ru/recipes/show/Salaty/10
Если я ввожу http://site.ru/recipes/show/Salaty/10/5 возвращается та же страница что и при http://site.ru/recipes/show/Salaty/10

Код routers.php:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['default_controller'] = "site";
$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";
$route['sitemap\.xml'] = "sitemap";
$route['sitemap_1\.xml'] = "sitemap_1";
$route['sitemap_forum\.xml'] = "sitemap_forum";
$route['info\.php'] = "info";

$route['translitAll'] = "lib/translitAll";

$route['^([0-9]+)_(.*?)(|/(\d+))$'] = "lib/show/$2/$1/$4/1/0";

$route['pregnant'] = "lib/main/pregnant";
$route['pregnant/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(:num)'] = "lib/show/$1/$2";
$route['pregnant/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(:num)/(:num)'] = "lib/show/$1/$2/$3";
$route['pregnant/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)'] = "lib/main/pregnant/$1";

$route['search/((live)(.+)?)'] = "search/$1";
$route['search/(.+)?'] = "search/index/$1";

$route['subscribe/(.*?)'] = "subscribe/index/$1";

$route['names/name-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)'] = "names/show/$1";
$route['names/letter-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)'] = "names/letter/$1";

$route['marks/(.*?)'] = "marks/show/$1";

#$route['^(.*?)(|/(\d+))'] = "lib/show/$1/0/$3/1/0";

$route['(?!marks|search|about|feedback|admin|albums|article|automailing|blog|calendar|celebrities|comments|error|forum|friends|iupload|kids|lib|lists|mail|market|misc|names|notebook|pharmamed|subscribe|vitamishki|bioaron|nyda(?![\w\-_])|photos|polls|recipes|relevance_init|robot|site|old|user)([/a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)'] = "lib/main/$1";
```

Comment: Добавьте код роутера, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то добавил.

Comment: Вам нужно перестраивать (в идеале - полностью) логику вашего роутера, т.к. вы в последнем правиле, вот тут вот `([/a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)`, разрешаете добавлять сколько угодно сегментов к ссылке. Вообще удивительно, что эти правила работают. А еще не стоит заключать `/` в квадратные скобки, т.к. потом чёрт ногу сломит, пока будет разбираться в подобном роутинге.

Comment: @terron, а как мне это заменить в текущей конфигурации без кардинальных изменений?